# Scale Y and X axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I made the following plot, and the numbers are print to close together. How can I scale the the y and x axis?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
axis equal,
grid=both,
xmax=10,xmin=-10,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
]

\addplot coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Are you going to ask every detail ? Or should I make a particular plot that you have in mind?  :)

Comment: Add `width=15cm,` to axis options.

Comment: @percusse Yes, I been asking too many questions in a few minutes... sorry I am in hurry because I need to submit an assignment :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you. `width=15` will do.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you want to answer, or is there a duplicate somewhere?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am not sure of a duplicate. I will add an answer anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgfplots` can adjust the distance between the tick labels as the width/height of the varies. Hence you can change the width (or height) of the plot by passing `width = <dimen>` to the axis options:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=15cm,               %% here, adjust as suitable
%axis y line=center,
%axis x line=middle,
axis lines = middle,  %% instead of above two lines this one is enough
scaled ticks=false,
axis equal,
grid=major,
xmax=9,xmin=-9,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
]

\addplot coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The pdf such generated can be included in the main document using `\includegraphics`. If you want a uniform width for all the graphs, add it to the `\pgfplotsset` like

```
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm}
```

On ther other hand, you can define a style like

```
\pgfplotsset{
small/.style={
width=12cm,
height=,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
label style={font=\small},
max space between ticks=35,
}
}
```

and use it to maintain consistency:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\pgfplotsset{
small/.style={
width=12cm,
height=,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
label style={font=\small},
max space between ticks=35,
}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
small,             %% here
%axis y line=center,
%axis x line=middle,
axis lines = middle,  %% instead of above two lines this one is enough
scaled ticks=false,
axis equal,
grid=major,
tick label/.style={font=\large},
xmax=9,xmin=-9,
ymin=-10,ymax=10,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-10,...,10},
ytick={-10,...,10},
]

\addplot coordinates{(-3,1) (6,-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Refer to section 4.10.2, page 248 of `pgfplots` manual for more details.

Comment: How can we make the ticks multiples of pi such as -2pi,-pi,0,pi,2pi?

Answer (score 1):

A solution with PSTricks just 4 fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[Dx=2,Dy=2]{->}(0,0)(-10,-10)(10,10){18cm}{12cm}
    \psline[linecolor=blue]{*-*}(-3,3)(5,-3)
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]