# Scale X and Y differently

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I want the following three functions to be displayed, with the constant `A = [1,2,4]`

```
A*x^2*(1-x)^2
```

My initial MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside,dvipsnames]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, calrsfs, wasysym, verbatim, bbm, color, graphics, geometry, mathtools, cases, graphicx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,filecontents,pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $c$,
    ylabel = {$f(c)$},
]
% A=1
\addplot [
    domain=-0.1:1.1, 
    samples=500, 
    color=red,
]
{x^2 * (1-x)^2};
\addlegendentry{$c^2\,(1-c)^2$}
% A=2
\addplot [
    domain=-0.1:1.1, 
    samples=500, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {2 * x^2 * (1-x)^2};
\addlegendentry{$2\,c^2\,(1-c)^2$}
% A=4
\addplot [
    domain=-0.1:1.1, 
    samples=500, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {4 * x^2 *(1-x)^2};
\addlegendentry{$4\,c^2\,(1-c)^2$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which results in following output,

[image: Output: Y-axis needs to be scaled down to 0:1 as well]

Keeping the rest of the code same, I incorporated the code answered in the post [Scale Y and X axis in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202072/scale-y-and-x-axis-in-pgfplots) into the previous main code.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,filecontents,pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=15cm,
    axis lines = middle,  %% instead of above two lines this one is enough
    scaled ticks=false,
    axis equal,
    grid=major,
    ymax=1.2, ymin=0,
    xmax=1.2, xmin=-0.2,
    ytick={0,...,1.2}, 
    xtick={-0.2,...,1.2},
    xlabel = $c$,
    ylabel = {$f(c)$},
]
.
.
.
```

Which results in,

[image]

---

I want pgfplot to display an output similar to this,

[image]

**How can I do so? Which part of the code needs to appended?**

Comment: The `Package PGF Math` errors, (1) Unknown operator `y` or `yt` (in `-0.2 ytick`) & (2) Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `0`, have been resolved somehow by commenting out `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and   `\tikzexternalize` in the preamble.

Comment: ...by **including** `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize` in the preamble

Comment: If you want to keep the size of the x and y scale the same but `axis equal` isn't what you are searching for, then you might want to try `axis equal image`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454152/95441 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449617/95441.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the axis equal option.
You can use ymin/ymax to narrower values.
I also added enlargelimits to extend axes by 1% in each direction.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,  %% instead of above two lines this one is enough
    scaled ticks=false,
%   axis equal,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num = 1,
%   xmin=-0.2,
%   xmax=1.2,
    ymin=-0.05, ymax=.4,
%   restrict y to domain=-0.1:0.4,
    enlargelimits=.01,
    xlabel = $c$,
    ylabel = {$f(c)$},
    width=10cm,
    height=5cm,
    ]
    % A=1
    \addplot [
    domain=-0.1:1.1, 
    samples=500, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {x^2 * (1-x)^2};
    \addlegendentry{$c^2\,(1-c)^2$}
    % A=2
    \addplot [
    domain=-0.1:1.1, 
    samples=500, 
    color=green,
    ]
    {2 * x^2 * (1-x)^2};
    \addlegendentry{$2\,c^2\,(1-c)^2$}
    % A=4
    \addplot [
    domain=-0.1:1.1, 
    samples=500, 
    color=orange,
    ]
    {4 * x^2 *(1-x)^2};
    \addlegendentry{$4\,c^2\,(1-c)^2$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @NBur, this worked!, got to know about the `enlargelimits` option from your answer. How to mark `0.3` and `0.1` value on Y-axis?

Comment: Got it!, increasing the width and height automatically includes them!

Comment: @b.kedar you can use `ytick={0,.1,...,.4}` to specify the marks on y-axis (but set also `grid=major` instead of `both`). Maybe you want to remove `minor tick num = 1`.

Comment: @b.kedar Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.